# Sentence Translations with an Emphasis on 被 and other general sentences

Tags: translation

I translated these sentences. I just wanted to make sure they made sense. If there is anything I can fix, please tell me. Thank you very much.

1. My leg hit the ground and was injured.

我的腿撞到地上，被受伤了。

2. He was seriously ill and was sent to the hospital.

他病得很重了， 被送往医院了。

3. We both fell on the lawn. Fortunately, we were not injured.

我们两个草坪上摔倒了。幸好，我们没有被受伤了。

4. The taxi driver's injury is not as severe as the bus driver's

出租车司机的受伤没有巴士司机的那么严重。

5. Five bicycles were stolen last week, and the thieves have not been found yet.

上个星期五辆自行车被偷了，还没有被找到小偷们。

6. The color, size, and style of the jacket fits you.

夹克的颜色，大小，和款式适合你。

7. The jacket is a little too loose.

夹克有一点儿太松。

8. The pants are thin and long, making your legs look long.

裤子又瘦又长，让你的腿看起来很长。

9. The Skirt is not too long or too short. You look beautiful wearing it.

裙子不是太长或太短。你穿裙子看起来很漂亮。

10. The department store is having a special sales event this weekend.

这个周末百货商店有一个特别销售活动。

Comment: Take ```injured``` as an adjective, rather than a passive action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*我的腿撞到地上，被受伤了*--> **我的腿撞到地上被弄伤了** (受伤 is an intransitive verb and it doesn't work in the passive voice. Similarly, we don't say 被死去了 or 被昏倒了)

*他病得很重了， 被送往医院了。* --> **他病得很重， 被送往医院了。** (we only need one final particle 了 in the same sentence)

*我们两个草坪上摔倒了。幸好，我们没有被受伤了。* --> **我们两个在草坪上摔倒了。幸好没有被弄伤。** (need preposition 在 before 草坪. Again, 受伤 is an intransitive verb and it doesn't work in the passive voice and you don't need to repeat the subject 们两 = 我们)

*出租车司机的受伤没有巴士司机的那么严重。* --> **出租车司机受的伤没有巴士司机的那么严重。** (的受伤 is not as native as 受的伤)

*上个星期五辆自行车被偷了，还没有被找到小偷们。* --> **上个星期五辆自行车被偷了，小偷们还没有被找到。** (with 被 before the verb 找到 the object 小偷们 should be placed before 被 and the verb)

*夹克的颜色，大小，和款式适合你。* --> **夹克的颜色，大小，和款式都适合你。** (add 都 after the last item on a list make it sound more complete)

*夹克有一点儿太松。* --> **夹克有点儿太松。** (一点儿 can be reduced to 点儿 or 点)

*裤子又瘦又长，让你的腿看起来很长。* --> **这裤子又窄又长，让你的腿看起来很长。**。(瘦 for thin is normally for people or animal, for objects, we use 幼 or 窄 for thin

*裙子不是太长或太短。你穿裙子看起来很漂亮。* --> **裙子不太长不太短。你穿起來很漂亮。** (no need to repeat 裙子 in the same sentence)

*这个周末百货商店有一个特别销售活动。* --> **这个周末这間百货商店有一个特别销售活动**。 ('这間百货商店' specify a particular store; while '百货商店' refers to all 百货商店 in general)

Comment: Thank you very much. For questions 3, it is ok to say 被受伤？

Comment: @a23 Sorry, I forgot to edit question 3. It is the same reason as question 1. 被受伤 is not a thing, Now is corrected to 被弄伤

Answer (score 1):

被受伤 isn't quite grammatical because 受 itself implies a passive voice.

受伤 = be injured

受骗 = be tricked/lied to/scammed

Or more generally, 受到了 = be on the receiving end of something

Answer (score 0):

The correct expression is:

> 我的腿撞到地上，**受伤**了。

Because

> 受 = 被 [passive mark]
>
> 伤 = injure
>
> 受伤 = be injured